# Using Let's Encrypt Wildcard Certificate on Multiple Servers

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, wildcard-subdomain

I have a series of subdomains that are a part of a root domain I manage. I have set up `certbot` on one of these domains: `x.example.com` and it is successfully using the certificate and renewing it automagically.

I now want to create a new subdomain y on a different server in our infrastructure. I need to use the same Let's Encrypt certificate since the challenge is good for any wildcard domains. However, using for example `certbot --nginx ...` issues a new challenge and that's no good. I want to use my same certbot stuff from `x`.

Is there a way to do this? Perhaps using the old challenge? I see `--force-renewal` and such that talk about `if the certificate already exists for the request domains...`. It doesn't seem like it fetches a copy of the certificate from their server however. I'd like to have it configure my nginx stuff automatically so I don't have to copy things over (via `--nginx`).

How do I do this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you created a wildcard cert when you didn't need to. It's perfectly reasonable for Server X and Server Y to both have their own copy of certbot generating and renewing a certificate only for the name(s) they care about. They can even share some names.

As long as you don't run up against the Let's Encrypt [rate limits](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/rate-limits/), you'll be fine.

Challenge validations are not permanent. You will generally have to re-validate a challenge during every renewal (usually between 60-90 days after original issuance).

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense. I'll just generate a new one for the new subdomain. I think you're right and I was too eager to create a wildcard cert. Do you usually use wildcard certificates for single server multiple subdomain scenarios?

Comment: It really depends on the number of sub-domains. A single cert can contain multiple names (also known as SANs or Subject Alternative Names). With Let's Encrypt specifically, you can create a cert with up to 100 distinct names in it. Wildcards are usually only used when you have dynamically created services where you don't know what the sub-domains will be in advance. Though some people make them just to be lazy, heh.

Comment: Thanks for clarifiation. Helped me a lot to understand. I thought using a letsencrypt wildcard would somehow bind me (and all subdomains) to the one machine I was using to retrieve the certificate.