# curl and wget fail to verify wildcard Let's Encrypt certificate, but browsers work fine

Tags: ssl-certificate, curl, wget

We've obtained a wildcard certificate from Let's Encrypt for `civility.social` and `*.civility.social`, using certbot. This works fine on all browsers and with curl and wget when verifying https://civility.social, or `https://graphql.civility.social`. The A records for those (sub)domains point to the same server, from which the certbot challenge was completed.

Later we've added a subdomain hosted on a different server, `meet.`. To [use the same certificate on a different server](https://serverfault.com/questions/914798/using-lets-encrypt-wildcard-certificate-on-multiple-servers), we copied the files making up the wildcard certificate from the original server to `meet.`. Both servers use NGINX. The problem is that `wget` and `curl` fail to fetch anything from `meet.civility.social`, even though browsers don't complain. `wget` fails even with `--no-check-certificate`.

```
$ $ wget -v --debug --no-check-certificate https://meet.civility.social
Setting --check-certificate (checkcertificate) to 0
Setting --check-certificate (checkcertificate) to 0
DEBUG output created by Wget 1.20.3 on linux-gnu.

Reading HSTS entries from ~/.wget-hsts
URI encoding = ‘UTF-8’
Converted file name 'index.html' (UTF-8) -> 'index.html' (UTF-8)
--2020-06-26 21:39:15--  https://meet.civility.social/
Resolving meet.civility.social (meet.civility.social)... 157.245.170.94
Caching meet.civility.social => 157.245.170.94
Connecting to meet.civility.social (meet.civility.social)|157.245.170.94|:443... connected.
Created socket 3.
Releasing 0x000055ae59be63e0 (new refcount 1).
Initiating SSL handshake.
SSL handshake failed.
Closed fd 3
Unable to establish SSL connection.


$ curl https://meet.civility.social/
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

What might be going on here?

Comment: I'd venture a guess and say it works ONLY in your browser, SSL Labs fails to connect as well with "No secure protocols supported".

Answer (score 1):

You need to update `ca-certificates` package.

On my machine I have no SSL errors:

```
mvutcovici@DESKTOP-QMNRLV6:~$ curl -v https://graphql.civility.social
*   Trying 167.71.155.126:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to graphql.civility.social (167.71.155.126) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=civility.social
*  start date: Jun  6 08:45:19 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Sep  4 08:45:19 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "graphql.civility.social" matched cert's "*.civility.social"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x563dffb227c0)
> GET / HTTP/2
> Host: graphql.civility.social
> user-agent: curl/7.68.0
> accept: */*
>
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 128)!
< HTTP/2 500
< server: nginx/1.17.10 (Ubuntu)
< date: Sat, 27 Jun 2020 05:27:14 GMT
< content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< content-length: 153
< access-control-allow-origin: *
< etag: W/"99-9KmtOnsArqM8/UCTY4AvEYVjSiM"
< strict-transport-security: max-age=63072000
<
{"errors":[{"message":"Context creation failed: Incorrect method GET from 199.241.131.83 requesting {}","extensions":{"code":"INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR"}}]}
* Connection #0 to host graphql.civility.social left intact
mvutcovici@DESKTOP-QMNRLV6:~$
```

**Edit 1:**

For meet.civility.social the webserver is not sending the intermediate certificate. You can see this with a network capture in WireShark. You are presenting only the certificate which covers `*.civility.social` and `civility.social`, but the intermediate certificate `Let's Encrypt Authority X3` is omitted. `certbot` should take care of installing the proper intermediate certificate, for more details see: https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/

You need to concatenate the server and intermediate certificate:

```
# civility.social
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
# Let's Encrypt Authority X3
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: graphql works, it's the new domain (ie. meet.civility.social) which doesn't.

Comment: I've updated my answer